# $rootScope value undefined

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm defining a rootScope variable after making a login in my application, the strange thing is that the value is declared in parts undefined.

```
 $rootScope.username = data.nombre;
 $rootScope.userImage = data.photo;
```

These variables are declared and contain a value because I have checked, for example. This variable is defined in LoginController, then I use in HomeCtrl and this works quite well. But to use it in the declaration of a menu fails and is not recognized.

**EDIT**

In this state I need to pass the value of the variable and which can not not even a service (not that does not work is that I can not think the way) I thought that $ rootScope would work. This state has no controller according defini I needed guidance on how to run a driver for it so to pass the variables that need to be displayed.

```
.state('eventmenu', {
  url: "/event",
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: "event-menu.html"
})
```

Comment: Try using $scope instead of $rootScope

Comment: did you inject $rootScope to your controller? $scope goes naturally, while $rootScope needs to be injected

Comment: You can use rootScope in your controllers via DI pattern, but when you include a partial in your page(such as side-bar or sth else),  you need to handle it by yourself.

Comment: You shouldn't be using rootScope to pass around values. That is what Services are for.

Comment: @shershen My problem is that I have a defined for this control.

Comment: @MoeFar to respect "for yourself"?

Comment: @MBielski I understand, should pass all values through service. The problem is that my State is abstract and you do not have a defined controller, that's my big question and problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some more code would have been helpful, especially the controller where you are using $rootScope.
With the given data i can point to a common pitfall: not properly injecting $rootScope in the controller.
$rootScope being a service needs to be injected in the controller.
Example:

```
module.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$rootScope',function($scope, $rootScope) {
  ...
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, edit the post and make it clear that I have no driver for my state of lateral menu, that's my mistake and my big question, whether to take driver, if I so everything is solved.